# How to add extra height on top only for iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a button that goes all the way to the top of the screen, under the status bar. In the center of the button is a '+' sign. This looks ok on all iPhones except for the iPhone X. For the iPhone X the button should be taller because the '+' is too close to the notch. Is there a way of doing this in a Storyboard?

[image]

[image]

Comment: adjust top constraint to add button when it was iPhone x alone'

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to use **Safe Area constraints**. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area).
It will automatically adjust the button appropriately (based on a device) after you set a top safe area constraint in the IB.

[image: Adding safe area constraints]

Now, if you really want to detect if the app is running on the iPhone X there is a hack you can use. However, be careful with it, **because this is definitely not the right solution and you should avoid it**.

```
if let mainWindow = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window, (mainWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0) > 0.0 {
    // Iphone X
}
```

**EDIT**

What I meant by using the safe area constraints is that you can create a dummy UIView as a placeholder to properly place a button. What I've done is, I've created a view and set the following constraints: top safe area, leading, trailing and height. I can then either center the button vertically in the whole area (first image) or just in the area below the status bar.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This does not solve this isse, using safe area. Safe area would mean my button is entirely beneath the notch. I want it to go all the way under the notch so the button background goes to the top of the device screen. It should just be bigger because of the increased notch size.

Comment: @JorisMans, I've edited the question and added two examples. Everything is done in the IB. Height is increased in both provided examples (on iPhone X), the only difference is the vertical alignment of the button.

Comment: "you can create a dummy UIView as a placeholder to properly place a button.". Still makes no sense to me. I want with 1 configuration in interface builder have the button look like your first image on any "normal" iPhone and like the second image on an iPhone X. I understand how I can manually do this in IB, but I want to do one configuration that will work for both devices. With a fixed setting for the safe area it will be either your first 2 images or either your last 2, but never a mix between them.